# Manufacturer amperage rating for cables VS ampacity chart

Tags: power-supply, wire, amperage

Whenever I am shopping for electrical cables on stores such as Amazon or Ebay, I often encounter cables with a maximum amperage rating that is way above what I can find in "ampacity charts". Why is that?

For example, the following listing on Amazon
https://www.amazon.ca/WINDYNATION-Welding-Battery-Copper-Inverter/dp/B017GB470O

states that a size 2 AWG cable can handle a maximum amperage of 205. However, if I look at an ampacity chart, I find out that the maximum is around 115 A. Why is the seller rating almost 100 A above? Is it a scam?

As another example, take this 12 V inverter with 4000 W continuous output and 8000 W peak power. : https://www.amazon.ca/Inverters-Outlets-Terminal-Wireless-Controller/dp/B09XDD6BYY

Along with the inverter, they give a 2 AWG cable, and as I've noted before, the ampacity charts give a 115 A rating for this size. To be able to generate 4000 W using 12 V, I would need 4000 W / 12 V = 333.3 A continuous. Wouldn't this be a fire hazard?

Comment: I don't have time to write a full answer, but I think the key issue is: there is no one maximum current rating for a wire. Putting current through a wire creates heat. The maximum safe current will depend on (1) how fast heat is removed (which will affect temperature), and (2) how much of a problem the heat is for the particular circumstances or application.

Comment: Looking through Annex B in the 2020 NEC (Ampacities annex), the only place a #2 AWG conductor gets close to a 200A rating is for the case - Table B.2(10) - of three single-insulated conductors directly buried in earth at 20C, using 75C USE cable.  That gets an Ampacity of 209A. Table B.2(1) for a 2-3 multiconductor cable in 30C air, one tops out at 119A for 90C rated (variety of) cables.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First off, technical ratings from listings on Amazon/Ebay/Alibaba/etc are to be taken with a value-sized grain of salt, if not disregarded entirely.  There is no accountability for the sellers, no real reputational damage for selling shoddy or downright dangerous products, and therefore no incentive to make their ratings even remotely reflect reality.

With that out of the way, the ratings for cables are a reflection of the conductor and the insulation together.  The conductor has some resistance per unit length, which translates (through resistive heating) into heat generation per unit length per amp.  When this heat generation affects the material properties of the insulation (softening, melting, burning), you have a thermal limit and therefore a current limit.  So if you've got a low melting point insulation such as PVC, the amount of current you can pass through a given diameter of wire is less than if you have a higher melting point insulation such as PTFE.  Installation also affects this: what's the ambient temperature?  Is the wire in the middle of a bundle of other wires which are all generating heat too?  Responsible manufacturers and vendors will assume plausible worst-case scenarios and use this to give you an ampacity that has reasonable safety margins.  Others do not.  Still others just put down a number that's better than the competitor's.

That said, the wire you linked has EPDM rubber insulation which is rated to 125 C continuous, while PVC is only rated to 104 C, so you'd expect EPDM wire to have a slightly higher ampacity than an equivalent gauge with PVC.  We use some 2 gauge EPDM wire that is supposedly rated for 190 A at 86 F ambient, but we are derating to about half of that.

Comment: +1 for no accountability on Amazon sellers. IMO it's turned into nearly the same thing as other international marketplace deep-discount retailers.

Comment: They may also be taking into account that the device in question won't be in continuous operation.